# Variable in external js file not being set

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I have run into something that seems pretty weird to me, although there's a good chance it's just a basic knowledge gap issue. As you can see, the following execution within the Node console produces the desired result, i.e. outputting the number of account addresses stored in `accounts`:

```
> var Web3 = require("web3");
undefined
> var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
undefined
> var accounts;
undefined
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(_accounts => { accounts = _accounts });
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> console.log(accounts.length);
10
undefined
```

However, running an external js file containing the exact same code

```
var Web3 = require("web3");

var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var accounts;
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(_accounts => { accounts = _accounts });

console.log(accounts.length);
```

produces the following error:

```
➜  ethtest node test.js
/home/brandon/ethtest/test.js:8
console.log(accounts.length);
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/brandon/ethtest/test.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

What could be the difference? Am I simply attempting something that cannot be done? Any help will be much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is because the code is executed asynchronously.

Then `then` clausule is executed when the call to `getAccounts` has returned the result. But the `console.log` is executed immediately after `getAccounts` and before the `then` function.

A solution is to also wait before logging.

```
var Web3 = require("web3");

var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var accounts;
web3.eth.getAccounts()
.then(_accounts => { accounts = _accounts })
.then(() => { console.log(accounts.length); });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answer, minus the semicolon after `.then(_accounts => { accounts = _accounts })`.

Comment: You are right, I did forgot to remove the semicolon. It is fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try, var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(_accounts => { 
accounts = _accounts 
console.log(accounts.length)
});
```